# ¿Por qué mi botón "igual" siempre devuelve 0? Calculadora Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy empezando a aprender *JavaScript* y se me ocurrió hacer una calculadora porque me parecía algo que contiene una buena lógica para comenzar con el lenguaje.

El punto es que no sé si tengo un error sintáctico o alguna función no hace lo que yo pienso que haría y el botón <kbd>=</kbd> (igual) siempre me devuelve 0.

A continuación dejo el código, espero que alguno pueda ayudarme:

```js
var a;
var b;
var operacion;
//var r = 1;

//Eventos

uno.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "1";
}
dos.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "2";
}
tres.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "3";
}
cuatro.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "4";
}
cinco.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "5";
}
seis.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "6";
}
siete.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "7";
}
ocho.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "8";
}
nueve.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "9";
}
cero.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "0";
}

reset.onclick = function(e){
    resetear();
}

suma.onclick = function(e){
    a = resultado.textContent;
    operacion = "+";
    limpiar();
}
resta.onclick = function(e){
    a = resultado.textContent;
    operacion = "-";
    limpiar();
}
multiplicacion.onclick = function(e){
    a = resultado.textContent;
    operacion = "*";
    limpiar();
}
division.onclick = function(e){
    a = resultado.textContent;
    operacion = "/";
    limpiar();
}
/*exponente.onclick = function(e){
    a = resultado.textContent;
    operacion = "x^";
    limpiar();
}
raiz.onclick = function(e){
    a = resultado.textContent;
    operacion = "√";
    limpiar();
}*/
igual.onclick = function(e){
    b = resultado.textContent;
    resolver();
}
function limpiar(){
    resultado.textContent = "";
  }
function resetear(){
    resultado.textContent = "";
    a = 0;
    b = 0;
    operacion = "";
}
function resolver(){
    var res = 0;
    switch(operacion){
        case "+":
            res = parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b);
        break;
        case "-":
            res = parseFloat(a) - parseFloat(b);
            break;
        case "*":
            res = parseFloat(a) * parseFloat(b);
            break;
        case "/":
            res = parseFloat(a) / parseFloat(b);
            break;
        /*case "x°":
            for(let i=b; i<0; i++){
                r = r * a;
            }
            break;*/
    } 
    resetear();   
    resultado.textContent = res;
}
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #c76464, #a57eda);
}

.container{
    display: grid;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 100px);
    grid-template-rows: minmax(120px, auto) repeat(5, 100px);
}
.container button{
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 2rem;
    border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    background-color: #ffffffc0;
}
.output{
    grid-column: 1/-1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 10px;
    /*para q no salga del output*/
    word-wrap: break-word;
    /* word-break: break-all;*/
    background-color: #a2c6f6;    
    border: 1px solid #e6e6e6af;
}

.output span{
    color: #000000;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
}
.igual{
    grid-column: -4/-1;
    width: 100%;
}
.igual button{
    width: 100%;
}
.c button{
    width: 100%;
}
button:hover{
    background-color: #ffffffe5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    <title>Calculadora</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="output">
            <span id="resultado"></span>
        </div>  

        <button id="siete">7</button>
        <button id="ocho">8</button>
        <button id="nueve">9</button>
        <button id="division">/</button>
        <button id="cuatro">4</button>
        <button id="cinco">5</button>
        <button id="seis">6</button>
        <button id="multiplicacion">*</button>
        <button id="uno">1</button>
        <button id="dos">2</button>
        <button id="tres">3</button>
        <button id="resta">-</button>
        <button id="raiz">√</button>            
        <button id="cero">0</button> 
        <button id="exponente">x^</button>
        <button id="suma">+</button>

        <div class="c">            
            <button id="reset">C</button>
        </div>
        <div class="igual">      
            <button id="igual">=</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Sé que ese *switch* se ve raro, podría utilizar un *for*, ¿será ahí donde fallo?, ¿será `var r = 0;`?

> **PD:** ¿Me conviene aprender vanilla JavaScript (js puro) o debería aprender react/vue, sugerencias?

Comment: A que te refieres por devolver cero? Si se presiona el igual, siempre devuelve cero? Si es asi, en la funcion `resolver` hay una variable `res` que esta declarado como "0", cosa que si no se cumple alguna condicion siempre sera ese valor por defecto

Comment: Ejecutándolo desde aquí me funciona bien, me efectúa el cálculo correctamente. El switch no me parece mal, podrías mejorar haciendo `var res = parseFloat(a);` y luego `res += parseFloat(b);`, etc. Al igual que `resultado.textContent += "1";`. Podrías mejorar que en lugar de tener un `onclick` por cada botón, tener uno genérico que lea la propiedad del botón y sepa qué valor u operación es.

Comment: En cuanto a tu ultima pregunta, esta basada en opiones ya que pides recomendaciones

Comment: @Andrew efectivamente, ahora me funciona, no sé si ya estaba saturado o debía cerrarlo por un rato. Muchas gracias por los consejos!

Comment: @JuanRivera más que nada pido opiniones en cuanto al sector laboral, teniendo en cuenta que el sector de desarrollo web y la programación en general cambia constantemente¿qué es más viable?.
Si alguno quería dejar su punto de vista o experiencia.

Comment: Javascript es la base de un montón de frameworks, sin dudas que necesitás saberlo para poder aprender React, Angular, Require, etc., etc... Por cierto, las calculadoras al presionar el operador no se borra el número, sino recién al ingresar otro dígito. Implica un poco más de lógica, pero quizás te interese mejorar eso. En una calculadora si oprimes `2` `*` `=` te devuelve `4`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Descarta la función `resetear` al momento de imprimir el resultado debido a que esta vacía el resultado, definimos una variable `doResult : Boolean` donde almacenaremos el valor inicial: false, luego al calcular el resultado cambiará a `true`, al momento de presionar cualquier botón, si `doResult` es `true`, no se añadirá el texto y se llamará a la función `resetear`

```js
var a;
var b;
var operacion;
var doResult = false;

function processNumb(n, o) {
  if (doResult ==true){resetear();}
  if (o === true) {
    a = resultado.textContent;
    operacion = "+";
    limpiar();
  } else {
    resultado.textContent += n;
  }
}

document.querySelectorAll(".numb").forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("click", e => {
    processNumb(parseInt(e.target.innerText));
  });
});

document.querySelectorAll(".opp").forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("click", e => {
    processNumb(e.target.innerText, true);
  });
});

reset.onclick = function(e){
    resetear();
}

igual.onclick = function(e){
    b = resultado.textContent;
    resolver();
}
function limpiar(){
    resultado.textContent = "";
  }
function resetear(){
    resultado.textContent = "";
    a = 0;
    b = 0;
    operacion = "";
    doResult = false
}
function resolver(){
    var res = 0;
    switch(operacion){
        case "+":
            res = parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b);
        break;
        case "-":
            res = parseFloat(a) - parseFloat(b);
            break;
        case "*":
            res = parseFloat(a) * parseFloat(b);
            break;
        case "/":
            res = parseFloat(a) / parseFloat(b);
            break;
        /*case "x°":
            for(let i=b; i<0; i++){
                r = r * a;
            }
            break;*/
    } 
    resultado.textContent = res;
    doResult = true;
}
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #c76464, #a57eda);
}

.container{
    display: grid;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 100px);
    grid-template-rows: minmax(120px, auto) repeat(5, 100px);
}
.container button{
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 2rem;
    border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    background-color: #ffffffc0;
}
.output{
    grid-column: 1/-1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 10px;
    /*para q no salga del output*/
    word-wrap: break-word;
    /* word-break: break-all;*/
    background-color: #a2c6f6;    
    border: 1px solid #e6e6e6af;
}

.output span{
    color: #000000;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
}
.igual{
    grid-column: -4/-1;
    width: 100%;
}
.igual button{
    width: 100%;
}
.c button{
    width: 100%;
}
button:hover{
    background-color: #ffffffe5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    <title>Calculadora</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="output">
            <span id="resultado"></span>
        </div>  

        <button id="siete" class="numb">7</button>
        <button id="ocho" class="numb">8</button>
        <button id="nueve" class="numb">9</button>
        <button id="division" class="numb">/</button>
        <button id="cuatro" class="numb">4</button>
        <button id="cinco" class="numb">5</button>
        <button id="seis" class="numb">6</button>
        <button id="multiplicacion" class="opp">*</button>
        <button id="uno" class="numb">1</button>
        <button id="dos" class="numb">2</button>
        <button id="tres" class="numb">3</button>
        <button id="resta" class="opp">-</button>
        <button id="raiz" class="opp">√</button>            
        <button id="cero" class="numb">0</button> 
        <button id="exponente" class="opp">x^</button>
        <button id="suma" clas="opp">+</button>

        <div class="c">            
            <button id="reset">C</button>
        </div>
        <div class="igual">      
            <button id="igual">=</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muy buen aporte, simplifica bastante!

Comment: Ojo con repetir tanto código, puede causar errores como en `cuatro.onclick`, donde no está ese chequeo. Mejor separar esa lógica en una función. Y como sugerí antes, mejor tener una única función que tome el valor de un atributo el botón. Tengan presente el concepto DRY: don't repeat yourself. Por cierto, "doResult" me parece un nombre poco claro, al leerlo no se entiende qué significa. Si además usas español, mejor seguir así. Quizás podrías llamarlo `calculoRealizado` o algo por el estilo.

Comment: Lo de separar en una función, me refería a separar TODA la lógica repetida, no sólo una parte. Por ejemplo: `uno.onclick = function(e){ procesarNumero(1); }` y listo. En `procesarNumero` haces todo lo repetitivo.

Comment: Ahí está mejor, aunque claramente `processNumb` no debería procesar operadores también, en vez de tener un parámetro extra y mezclar las lógicas en una función, deberían ser dos separadas.

Comment: El boton de la división da error, y los demás operadores cuando haces por ejemplo: "2*2=4" y luego das "=" nuevamente suma 2, lo mismo pasa con la resta. Igualmente agradezco tu tiempo para mejorar el código!